# Take a full and transaction log back up of SQL Server RDS database to S3 bucket

Tags: t-sql, amazon-s3, backup, amazon-rds

Recently we migrated to SQL Server RDS and I am trying to take full and transaction log backup from RDS to S3 bucket and I am also trying to automate this process. The reason I don't want to use the automated snapshot backup is because it is at the instance level not at the individual database level. It means if I want to restore the database it will restore the DB instance and  create a new DB instance.